# dom question: getting the full sourcode from a html document

Tags: html, dom

i'm trying things out with a html document's dom (under visualbasic6) and i was wondering:
how can i get the full html sourcecode including all headers?

is there something like document.all.value?

thanks

Comment: Care to elaborate exactly how you obtain the DOM object in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is a DOM, there is no way to retrieve the original source, much less the response headers. It's gone. The DOM is what was generated from the source, which was thrown away thereafter.

If you must have the original source and headers, you will have to fetch it again from the server, using the `location` object to get the URL. For example from inside a web page script:

```
var req= 'XMLHttpRequest' in window? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHttpRequest');
req.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (this.readyState===4) {
        alert('Headers: '+this.getAllResponseHeaders());
        alert('Body: '+this.responseText);
    }
};
req.open('get', location.href);
req.send(null);
```

Clearly this will only work for a page generated from a GET request.